# Getting the selected text from a select list using jQuery selector

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the selected text from a dropdown using a selector. If I reference the dropdown directly by name it works:

```
$('#aBigLongASP.NETWebformsGeneratedName_ddl_StateOfOption :selected').text()
```

I am however trying to use a selector to select the dropdown using only the last part of the name:

```
$('#select[id$='ddl_StateOfOption']) :selected).text();
```

but I can't quite seem to get it to work. The Chrome developer tool throws the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Can anyone point out where the error is?

Comment: The Stack Overflow syntax highlighter should have already pointed out one of the errors. You're nesting single quotes. Replace one set with double quotes.

Comment: Also get rid of the random closing parenthesis after the closing square bracket.

Comment: Vote to closer - care to justify?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('select[id$="ddl_StateOfOption"] :selected').text();
```

There were several problems with your code:

```
// $('#select[id$='ddl_StateOfOption']) :selected).text();
//    ^           ^                 ^ ^          ^
//    |           |                 | |           \
//    |           |                 |  \            missing closing '
//    |           \                 /   shouldn't have )
//    \            should be " not '
//     You were selecting elements with id "select" rather than tag "select"
```

Comment: Brilliant, its good to see what was wrong rather than just copy and paste the solution. I'd accept it again if I could!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#select[id$='ddl_StateOfOption'] :selected").text();
```

try this one.

Comment: Thanks, this also give an error - "unrecognized expression". @nnnnnn answer works.